# How to count the number of values that are being summed

Tags: python, pandas, count, sum

How can I count the number of values that are being summed?

I have a really large df, but lets say I have a df like this:

```
df1:

     A     B        C
0   John  Pen       Apple
1   John  Printer   Pie
2   John  Charger   Burger
3   Erick Battery   Pizza
4   Mandy Keyboard  Bread
5   Mandy Phone     Coffee
6   David Computer  Coke
```

And another df:

```
df2:

     A        B  
0   Pen       2
1   Printer   5
2   Charger   11
3   USB       5
4   Keyboard  8
5   Phone     21
6   Cup       3
```

And a third df:

```
df3: 

    A      B
0  Erick  Yes
1  John   Yes
2  David  No 
3  Mandy  Yes
4  Jared  No
5  Lisa   No
```

I summed the matching values

```
In: 

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='B', right_on='A', suffixes=('','1'))
df = df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B1'].sum()
df = pd.merge(df3, df, on='A', how='left').rename(columns={'B1':'Sum'}).fillna('')

Out:

    A      B   Sum
0  Erick  Yes  
1  John   Yes  18
2  David  No   
3  Mandy  Yes  29
4  Jared  No
5  Lisa   No
```

And now I'm trying to count the number of values that are being summed.
My desired df would be:

```
Out:

    A      B   Sum   Count
0  Erick  Yes          0
1  John   Yes  18      3
2  David  No           0
3  Mandy  Yes  29      2
4  Jared  No           0
5  Lisa   No           0
```

I know this might be very simple and obvious, but I'm still very new to python

How can I do it?

Comment: Share code to create df1, df2, df3?

Comment: I didn't used a code.
It's part of an excel file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the groupby method count()

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='B', right_on='A', suffixes=('','1'))

groups = df.groupby('A', as_index=False)
df = groups['B1'].sum()
df['count'] = groups.count()['B1']

df = pd.merge(df3, df, on='A', how='left').rename(columns {'B1':'Sum'}).fillna('')
```

Comment: This works, but only with one column. How con I aplly this to several columns at once. For example
df['count'] = groups.count()['A, 'B', 'C']

Comment: groups.count() computes all non nan values in each column for each group.  Above, I select column B1 because that what you used for sum(), but you can select any columns you'd like.

Comment: Add brackets to the labels for multiple labels df[['counta', 'countb', 'countc']] = groups.count()[['A, 'B', 'C']]

Comment: Thanks. I found that only selecting one column does the job. This solves it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [153]: df = df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B1'].agg(['sum','count']).reset_index()

In [154]: df = pd.merge(df3, df, on='A', how='left').rename(columns={'B1':'Sum'}).fillna('')

In [155]: df
Out[155]:
       A    B sum count
0  Erick  Yes
1   John  Yes  18     3
2  David   No
3  Mandy  Yes  29     2
4  Jared   No
5   Lisa   No
```